# Why does my 1440p HDMI monitor only display correctly when running from the bootable USB?

Tags: hardware, monitors, hdmi

I recently brought home a 1440p HDMI 60 Hz monitor. However, on Ubuntu and Fedora it has problems displaying correctly. Some images of the problem are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/szawh.jpg

Initially, I had Fedora installed, and thought it was a Fedora problem. Then, I wanted to try Ubuntu, figuring the VGA drivers might be different. I first loaded Ubuntu from the installation media, to try it out and voila! It worked! I decide to go ahead and install Ubuntu.

After I loaded Ubuntu from disk, my monitor started having the exact same problem it was having on Fedora.

The problem goes away when I set the monitor's resolution to 1080p.

Interestingly, the same problem appeared when the Ubuntu live USB version was loading. However, once it loaded, the problem went away!

What could the live version be doing that the installed version does not?

Edit: I tried running `xrandr` on both Live and Installed versions of Ubuntu and the resulting difference was interesting:

**Live**

```
ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440    59.95*+
   1920x1080    60.00   60.00   50.00   59.94   30.00   25.00   24.00   29.97   23.98  
   1920x1080i   60.00   50.00   59.94  
   1680x1050    59.88  
   1280x1024    75.02   60.02  
   1440x900     59.90  
   1280x960     60.00  
   1280x800     59.91  
   1152x864     75.00  
   1280x720     60.00   50.00   59.94  
   1440x576     50.00  
   1024x768     75.03   70.07   60.00  
   1440x480     60.00   59.94  
   832x624      74.55  
   800x600      72.19   75.00   60.32   56.25  
   720x576      50.00  
   720x480      60.00   59.94  
   640x480      75.00   66.67   60.00   59.94  
   720x400      70.08  
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080    60.00*+
   1680x1050    59.88  
   1280x1024    75.02   60.02  
   1440x900     59.90  
   1280x960     60.00  
   1280x720     60.00  
   1024x768     75.03   70.07   60.00  
   832x624      74.55  
   800x600      72.19   75.00   60.32   56.25  
   640x480      75.00   72.81   66.67   59.94  
   720x400      70.08
```

**Installed**:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+360 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 550mm x 310mm
   2560x1440     59.91*+
```

Edit 2: Also, I realized that this graphics artifact is causing some sort of striping that basically shows basically every other column of the display and double its width. When I am typing on that display, every other letter appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution, though I'd love some expanded input on whether this is an acceptable long term solution.

I followed the screenshot here:[image]

Which I found from the [debugging Wayland page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Wayland_problems#Are_you_running_a_Wayland_session.3F) Using both GNOME Classic and GNOME on Xorg allowed me to correctly run the HDMI monitor at 1440p. I could back switch into the normal GNOME 3 desktop without problems.

It seems that the problem comes back when I boot into the default GNOME 3. All I have to do to resolve the problem is to log in under GNOME Classic then log out and back in under regular GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

It's a miracle, that some distribution displays in full resolution via [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI), I don't have explanation for that.

My 1440p LCD displays correctly only via [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) in its native resolution.

Depending on its version, [HDMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI) is guaranteed to only put though 1080p.

More than that you need to connect via [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort).

Comment: Cables these days are not simple pieces of wire, they have logic to prevent their use in some situations, essentially in order to force you to buy the more expensive versions.  If your monitor works over DP but not over HDMI than either you need a more expensive HDMI cable, or your graphic card won't let you run higher resolutions over HDMI.  Another possibility is a messed up EDID entry in the monitor's firmware.  Do some research about your monitor and your graphic card, some people might have run into the same problems.

Comment: @SatōKatsura Thank you for your research. I wonder, what exactly is this artifact business thats going on with my screen called? I'm struggling to even research more into it because I'm failing to come up with adequate search terms.